# Updating Wifi status info at regular intervals in android

Tags: android, android-wifi, runnable

I know this question might be replica of another question but can someone help me figure out where I have gone wrong and possibly correct it if possible?

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    TextView ford;
    public String TAG=MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    protected static final long TIME_DELAY = 1000;
    //the default update interval for your text, this is in your hand , just run this sample
    TextView mTextView;
    Handler handler=new Handler();
    Random trust = new Random();
    int count =0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mTextView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview);}
        protected void onResume({

            super.onResume();handler.post(updateTextRunnable);}
            ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            Runnable updateTextRunnable=new Runnable(){
            public void run() {

                if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {

                    mTextView.setText("connected!");
                } else {

                    mTextView.setText("No network connection available.");
                }
            }
        };
    }
```

Comment: use a thread and check the wifi info

Comment: What error do you observe?

Answer (score 0):

Efficient way is to create a broacast receiver which will reguralry check wifi status. Register receiver like this-

```
 WifiMonitor wifiMonitor = new WifiMonitor();
    registerReceiver(wifiMonitor, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION));
    registerReceiver(wifiMonitor, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));

    public class WifiMonitor extends BroadcastReceiver {

            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    //do your work here
    }
}
```

Comment: as i said earlier .. i know how to check the status of connection .. what i want is the code that corresponds to the time factor.. i tried it with threads ,handlers runnables .. but all of them went in vain

Comment: Ok, for time factor, you can use Timer class of android. If you need code then tell me

Comment: Timer timer = new Timer();
long TWO_SECOND = 2 * 1000;
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
   @Override
   public void run() {
    //do your work here
   }
  }, 0, TWO_SECOND);